# SQL Syntax Error Exception in jdbc

Tags: mysql

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JdbcEx2 {
static final String username="root";
static final String password="MyAditya16*";
static final String driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
static final String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String sql,name;
    int id,marks;
    Statement st=null;
    Connection cn=null;
    char ch;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url+"?useSSL=false",username,password);
        st=cn.createStatement();
        //sql="create database student;";
        sql="drop database student;";
        int rows=st.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Database created");
        sql ="CREATE TABLE student (id INTEGER not NULL, name VARCHAR(255), marks INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY ( id ));";
        rows=st.executeUpdate("use student;"+sql);
        System.out.println("student table created");
        System.out.println("Do you want to insert some rows?");
        ch=sc.next().charAt(0);
        while (ch=='y'){
            System.out.println("Enter some data");
            sql="insert into student VALUES(?,?,?)";
            st=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.print("\nEnter id:");
            id=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\nEnter name:");
            name=sc.next();
            System.out.print("\nEnter marks:");
            marks=sc.nextInt();
            ((PreparedStatement) st).setInt(1,id);
            ((PreparedStatement) st).setString(2,name);
            ((PreparedStatement) st).setInt(3,marks);
        }
        cn.close();
        st.close();
        sc.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(st!=null){
                st.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }try{
            if(cn!=null){
                cn.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

it says:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE student (id INTEGER not NULL, name VARCHAR(255), marks INTEGER, PRI' at line 1

what is issue with this snippet

```
sql ="CREATE TABLE student (id INTEGER not NULL, name VARCHAR(255), marks INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY ( id ));";
```

Comment: what is ur myql server version ?

Comment: once ur database is dropped i m not sure how r u creating tables . this is the problem ??  sql="drop database student;"; is it ?

Comment: @user641887 my sqlserver version is 8.0.11.Drop table is not the thing...it will have same error if I'll create.

Comment: @user641887 please check the create table snippet which i have mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure executeupdate supports multiple statements in a single call?

Comment: @Shadow I think it'll be converted into string.

Comment: You misunderstood me. In the command string you have 2 statements: a `use` statement and a `create table` one. I'm not sure if the executeupdate method supports execution of both statements in a single call. You may have to break them up to multiple calls.